# Does Pebble C support simple http

Tags: http, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I know that Pebble.js JavaScript declares support for a very simple HTTP service (quaintly named "ajax"), but I can't find a similar facility in its C SDK.
Is it possible to make an HTTP request from Pebble C SDK?

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing a C app, you can use [AppMessage](https://developer.getpebble.com/2/guides/app-phone-communication.html) to send and receive messages to JavaScript running on the phone. The JavaScript code has access to standard HTTP functions (XMLHttpRequest).

[Part 3 of the Pebble tutorial](https://developer.getpebble.com/getting-started/watchface-tutorial/part3.html) shows you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, penny dropped.
The Pebble.js code runs on the phone, and interacts with the watch as an input/output device. All the js code processing occurs on the phone. So the "ajax" http calls originate fro the phone.
In the C SDK environment, the code is being executed on the watch and any communication wit the outside world has to be as messages over BlueTooth. So, in teh C environment, the HTTP servde has to be supplied by the phone's app.